# Spring Actuator returns 404 with Spring Boot (war project)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-actuator

I'm using Spring Boot 2.7.0 (but I've also tried 2.6.7 and 2.5) with Java 17, and I want to add [actuator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html) to the project. The project is packaged as a war because it's still using JSP's, which we haven't gotten to work when packing it as jar. It uses a very old version of spring-security (4.2.18.RELEASE, still using XML configuration) because of compatibility issues, but other than that, dependencies should be up-to-date. In other projects, I've never had any problems with actuator. Anyways I've added this to the `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

With these properties:

```
management.server.port=8081
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
management.endpoint.health.status.http-mapping.DOWN=200
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

We've added this setting to our spring security XML configuration to allow all calls to actuator:

```xml
<http pattern="/actuator/**" auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" create-session="stateless" disable-url-rewriting="true" security="none"/>
```

We have (a lot) of custom configuration, but the relevant parts that I can think of, are defined like this:

```java
@EnableRabbit
@EnableRetry
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@ComponentScan({"com.company.something", "com.company.another"})
@ImportResource(locations = {"classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml", "classpath:spring/webflow-config.xml"})
public class Bootstrap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Bootstrap.class, args);
    }
}
```

and

```java
@Configuration
public class WebappConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcatFactory() {
        return new CustomTomcatServletWebServerFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> servletContainerCustomizer() {
        return container -> {
            container.addContextCustomizers(ctx -> ctx.setReloadable(false));
            container.addConnectorCustomizers(con -> con.setMaxPostSize(5000000));
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/web-resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/");
    }


    @Bean
    public DispatcherServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServletRegistrationBean() {
        DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext());
        return new DispatcherServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/");
    }

    private static class CustomTomcatServletWebServerFactory extends TomcatServletWebServerFactory {
        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            ((StandardJarScanner) context.getJarScanner()).setScanManifest(false);
            context.setResources(new ExtractingRoot());
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the application I get this error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 2 of method servletEndpointRegistrar in org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - dispatcherServletRegistration: a programmatically registered singleton    - dispatcherServletRegistrationBean: defined by method 'dispatcherServletRegistrationBean' in class path resource [com/company/WebappConfiguration.class]
```

This is the first thing that I find pretty weird. From what I understand, Spring seems to detect two `servletEndpointRegistrar` beans. If I try to remove the `dispatcherServletRegistrationBean` I run into this error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method errorPageCustomizer in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletPath' that could not be found.
```

If I instead add the `@Primary` annotation to `dispatcherServletRegistrationBean`:

```java
@Primary
@Bean
public DispatcherServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServletRegistrationBean() {
    DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet();
    servlet.setApplicationContext(new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext());
    return new DispatcherServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/");
}
```

the application does indeed start. But if I navigate to `http://localhost:8081/actuator` all I get is this:

```json
<Map>
  <timestamp>2022-05-24T06:38:58.914+00:00</timestamp>
  <status>404</status>
  <error>Not Found</error>
  <message>No message available</message>
  <path>/actuator</path>
</Map>
```

What could be the cause of this and how can I solve it?

Comment: It is your own configuration that is breaking things. Remove the dispatcherservlet. I also don't really get all the other customized stuff. Your Spring Security version is probably also incompatible with the Spring version being used, and I'm not sure if WebFlow still works.

Comment: You're probably right, but I'm looking for hints that may interfere with the autoconfiguration of actuator. I've removed the dispatcherservlet, but then it doesn't work. I've also tried to change the name of "dispatcherServletRegistrationBean" to "dispatcherServletRegistration", then I don't need @Primary. But nothing changes, it still doesn't find the /actuator endpoint.

Comment: The registration of the dispatcherservlet and with an empty context, breaks a lot of auto configuration. Do you really need all the customizations on the context? The `maxPostSize` you can set through a property? I would suggest to ditch all of that configuration (maybe leave only the addition of the `addResourceHandlers`. You can also remove `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` as that is on by default and classbased is default as well (and can be configured through a property). Finally are you running this as a war or are you deploying it to a server?

Comment: @M.Deinum We're running it as a war, again we'd like to move to jar, but we have been unable to due so because of tiles and JSP.

Comment: JSP don't work in a jar so that is a futile attempt, move away from JSP I would say. I also just asked if you are running it as a war or deploy it to a tomcat, as that impacts what you can do/control with the actuator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this by creating the `DispatchServlet` as a separate bean from the `DispatcherServletRegistrationBean`:

```java
@Bean(name = DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DEFAULT_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_BEAN_NAME)
public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
    DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet();
    servlet.setApplicationContext(new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext());
    return servlet;
}

@Bean(name = DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DEFAULT_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_REGISTRATION_BEAN_NAME)
public DispatcherServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServletRegistration(DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet) {
    return new DispatcherServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet, "/");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Migrating to Spring-Security 6.x.x I've had an issue, where there was no `dispatcherServletRegistration` initialized for the actuator, which runs on a different port. Creating it at startup, like you did, fixed the issue.